# Pitch detection program problems

Tags: javascript, pitch

I have searched for a pitch detection program but nothing has given me the guidance I need. I am trying to use pitch.js but I can't put the microphone buffer into the program.

I am trying to create a program that uses the pitch of a singer to move an object up and down the screen. For this I need a continuous (or every 250ms or so) Pitch detection program and access to the microphone.
I am trying to use "pitch.js" but I cannot get the microphone buffer into “pitch.input”

```
  /* Copy samples to the internal buffer */

    pitch.input(inputBuffer);
```

The code I am using is:

```
var audioContext = new AudioContext();

console.log("audio is starting up ...");

var BUFF_SIZE = 16384;

var audioInput = null,
        microphone_stream = null,
        gain_node = null,
        script_processor_node = null,
        script_processor_node = null,
        analyserNode = null;

if (!navigator.getUserMedia)
    navigator.getUserMedia = navigator.getUserMedia || 
navigator.webkitGetUserMedia ||
                          navigator.mozGetUserMedia || 
navigator.msGetUserMedia;

if (navigator.getUserMedia) {

    navigator.getUserMedia({ audio: true },
          function (stream) {
              start_microphone(stream);
          },
          function (e) {
              alert('Error capturing audio.');
          }
        );

} else { alert('getUserMedia not supported in this browser.'); }

function start_microphone(stream) {

    gain_node = audioContext.createGain();
    gain_node.connect(audioContext.destination);

    microphone_stream = audioContext.createMediaStreamSource(stream);
    microphone_stream.connect(gain_node);

    // --- enable volume control for output speakers

    document.getElementById('volume').addEventListener('change', function () 
  { 
        var curr_volume = this.value;
        gain_node.gain.value = curr_volume;

        console.log("curr_volume ", curr_volume);
    });

    script_processor_node = audioContext.createScriptProcessor(2048, 1, 1);
    script_processor_node.connect(gain_node);

   function setPitch() {

    var pitch = new PitchAnalyzer(4100);

    /* Copy samples to the internal buffer */
    //This is where I have been having the problem.

    pitch.input(????);
    /* Process the current input in the internal buffer */

    pitch.process();
    var tone = pitch.findTone();

    if (tone === null) {
        console.log('No tone found!');
    } else {
        console.log('Found a tone, frequency:', tone.freq, 'volume:', 
 tone.db);
    }
}


</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Have you had a look at the demo? https://github.com/audiocogs/pitch.js-demo

Comment: I have tried several times to make pitch.js-demo work but I have not been able to. I have installed all libraries and there are no errors on the console but it just freezes with a small screen in the same spot that the program had just asked to access 'flash'. I am guessing it is a flash issue but my browser (Chrome on a Windows platform) seems to be up to date.

Comment: Problem solved! I found a resource called "Wad" at githum 
   https://github.com/rserota/wad  and it did exactly what I wanted!

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved! I found a resource called "Wad" at githum 
   https://github.com/rserota/wad  and it did exactly what I wanted!